# REST Gel all folders/subfolders and files in tree view using Ajax

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest, ajax, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to find a way to do this:  create a tree view of all items in the "Documents" library, with folders, subfolders, and items (links to items).

Im using _api fo get folders an files

```
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderRelativeUrl')?$expand=Folders,Files
```

all i get is the folders and the name of the files ! not all files but files in the root.

I want the result in treeView or Array

Example: For a Documents library created as this :

Folder 1
        Folder 1.1
Folder 2
        Folder 2.1
                text.txt
Folder 3

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef
```

You will have to built the correct tree structure yourself